# Joomla output override from plugin

Tags: php, joomla

Is there a way to override a component's output from a plugin? I'm aware of the concept of template overrides, but I just don't want to put the code into the template because

1. it simply feels wrong to put the code there because it is not a feature tied to the template. In my opinion the template should only contain overrides to fit core output into the template
2. I may want to add parameters to change behaviour (i.e. there is business logic involved and I want to keep it all together - in a plugin)
3. I may reuse it at another webpage and obviously don't want to copy & paste the code to all the templates I use

Or are my considerations wrong and the answer is: Just keep it simple and put it into the template?

I found a tutorial about [Adding custom fields to core components using a plugin](https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin) in the joomla documentation where the costom fields are addet to the view with a template override - which seems odd because the rest is done in a plugin - so i assume there is no way to to an output override from a plugin?

Comment: A key feature of web logic is that you separate the layout/presentation layer from everything else.  It sounds to me that part of what you want would be a layout and part would be a plugin.  If you want to use it repeatedly it makes more sense to do it as a JLayout  than as a traditional override though you may need to add an override that calls the layout, hard to say based on what you have posted.

Comment: I just thought it would be nice to keep all the code belonging to one "feature" (e.g. - to stay with the example I linked to - the code adding custom fields and the code showing those fields) at the same spot. So I don't have to install an plugin and create an override everywhere I want to use it. But if I have anderstood you right, presentation code does not belong into a plugin?

Comment: Well there's a whole debate about that. Really plugins shouldn't have layout ... but you will find many that do anyway.